# Best approach to assess meta-analysis heterogeneity when a study has sampling variance of zero

Tags: r, meta-analysis, heterogeneity, metafor

I am currently performing analyses for a meta-analysis looking at the mean difference of pre-post intervention data (i.e., 'mean change'). However, one study reports identical mean and SD for the pre- and post-intervention measures. This means that the mean difference is 0 — not an issue — but the standard deviation of the mean difference also evaluated to 0, hence the sampling variance is 0.

When this study is included in the random effects model, using the `metafor` package, it is unable to perform the Q test or provide estimates of heterogeneity stats and their 95% CIs.

```
Warning messages:
1: There are outcomes with non-positive sampling variances. 
2: Cannot compute Q-test, I^2, or H^2 when there are non-positive sampling variances in the data.
```

What are acceptable approaches to dealing with this study? I do not want to omit it since the effect is important to the message, but it is also important that I demonstrate the heterogeneity present in these studies.

Would it ok to re-run the analysis omitting the offending study and presenting the heterogeneity stats, making it clear that the study was omitted due to limitations in running the tests?

Comment: That seems to imply that the pre-post correlation in that study was 1 which seems unlikely.

Comment: I agree it is unlikely and the estimated correlation based on the *p*-value evaluates to 1.0. Unfortunately, the study reports outcomes to the nearest whole unit—had they reported to at least 1 decimal (which is how it should be for this variable) there is likely to have been a small difference.

Comment: "However, one study reports identical mean and SD for the pre- and post-intervention measures. This means that the [...] standard deviation of the mean difference also evaluated to 0, hence the sampling variance is 0." I might be misunderstanding something here but this isn't how uncertainty propagation works (unless you make an assumption about the covariance that you haven't justified, see the first comment).

Comment: @Roland I think you are correct. Perhaps we need more details to work out what is going on here.